# Merge custom fields in checkout page with shipping fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, checkout

I'm trying to move custom fields that I created on my checkout page in the Shipping block.

What I've tried is this code: `thise are the new fields`

```
// Add a new checkout field
function filter_checkout_fields($fields){
    
    $fields['extra_fields'] = array(
            'some_field' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'required'      => false,
                'label' => __( 'Field 1:' )
                ),
            'another_field' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'required'      => false,
                'label' => __( 'Field 2:' )
                ),

    return $fields;

    
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'filter_checkout_fields' );

// display the extra field on the checkout form
function extra_checkout_fields(){ 

    $checkout = WC()->checkout(); ?>

    <div class="extra-fields">
    <h3><?php _e( 'Title' ); ?></h3>

    <?php 
    // because of this foreach, everything added to the array in the previous function will display automagically
    foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['extra_fields'] as $key => $field ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

   <?php }
   add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ,'extra_checkout_fields' );
```

And this is how I'm trying to move them (replace current fields)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'another_group' );
 
function another_group( $checkout_fields ){
 
    // 1. We assign a field array to another group here
    $checkout_fields['some_field'] = $checkout_fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'];
    $checkout_fields['another_field'] = $checkout_fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name'];
    
    // 2. Remove a field from a previous location
    unset( $checkout_fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] );
    unset( $checkout_fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name'] );
 
    return $checkout_fields;
 
}
```

What is happening is that the `['shipping_first_name']` and `['shipping_last_name']` are removed (unset) but nothing appeared on their place.

Is this possible to happen at all?

Answer (score 1):

you can set priority of custom field with your old field priority like below
$fields['shipping']['some_field']['priority'] = 10;
$fields['shipping']['another_field']['priority'] = 20;

Comment: So, you mean that with the priority I can move them there (inside shipping block) and then with just unset the fields that I don't need?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't had a chance to test this yesterday. Will do it today and will come back to accept the answer or for additional information if need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just unset the fields that you don't need as you do already but don't try to override them in this function

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'another_group' );
 
function another_group( $checkout_fields ){
         
    // 2. Remove a field from a previous location
    unset( $checkout_fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] );
    unset( $checkout_fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name'] );

     // ... more fields for unset here
 
    return $checkout_fields;
 
}
```

Then in your function where you have `[extra_fields]` change it to `[shipping]` this will place the custom fields in the shipping block.

```
// Add a new checkout field
function filter_checkout_fields($fields){
    
    $fields['shipping'] = array(
        'some_field' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'required'      => false,
            'label' => __( 'Field 1:' )
            ),
              ... so on
```

Comment: Well.. that's was easy. I don't know how I didn't think of this way, Thank you very much.